# how to permit one of the parameters to be arbitrary hash using strong_parameters?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, strong-parameters

I have a model with one of the fields being `serialise :config, JSON`.

it should permit any hash as a value. But I can't quite see a clean way to do it with `strong_parameters`.

my current solution is:

```
def resource_params
  p = params.require(:model)
  config = dp.slice(:config).permit!
  p.delete(:config)
  [p.permit(:foo, :bar, ...).merge(config)]
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [strong_params gem page](https://github.com/rails/strong_parameters)

> To whitelist an entire hash of parameters, the permit! method can be used
>
> params.require(:log_entry).permit!

And also

> If you want to make sure that multiple keys are present in a params
> hash, you can call the method twice:
>
> params.require(:token)
> params.require(:post).permit(:title)

but I'm no expert on that matter.

Comment: this is not what I need. see example. I need one of the SUBparameters to allow arbitrary keys.

Comment: I don't understand your example but I'm pretty sure you can achieve this with what I mentioned. Can you maybe add example params and highlight what should be allowed?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use whitelisting:

```
def resource_params
  params.require(:model).permit(:foo, :bar, ...).tap do |whitelisted|
    whitelisted[:config] = params[:model][:config]
  end
end
```

You can find it here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#strong-parameters search for "4.5.4 Outside the Scope of Strong Parameters"